# Как запретить/разрешить выполнение javascript в определенной странице сайта?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Дано: сайт на CMS. Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы яваскрипт работал только на определенных страницах сайта.
Например, есть страницы:

1) сайт/страница1;

2) сайт/страница2;

3) сайт/страница/страница1.

Нужно, чтобы яваскрипт выполнялся в первом и последнем варианте. Во второй странице он выполняться не должен.

Пробовал так:

```
var need_location = '/сайт/страница1';

var need_location = '/сайт/страница/страница1';

if (window.location.pathname !== need_location){

//Здесь код который выполняться должен на 2х страницах только

}
```

Но не работает...

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант сойдёт?

```
var permitPath = [
    '/сайт/страница1',
    '/сайт/страница/страница1'
];

if(permitPath.indexOf(location.pathname) > -1){
    // код для путей в массиве
} else {
    // код для остальных страниц
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы присваиваете одной и той же переменной разные значения.